# Is there a need for https (i.e. ssl certificate) for my ec2 instances that are behind an elastic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, load-balancing

Suppose I have a website which whose communication I would like to encrypt using ssl. I have several (stateless) instances all behind an AWS elastic load balancer. AWS allows for me to set https on the load balancer using one of their ssl certificates.

The question is do I compromise security if I have the load balancer route calls to port 80 (via http) on my instances? I mean, I would like to be able to do without managing the ssl certificates if I can but I don't want to compromise on the security of my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may be better suited for the ServerFault community

Comment: are you running the ELB and ec2 instance in a VPS? is the ec2 instance in a private subnet?

Comment: @BretzL I believe you intended "VPC" rather than "VPS."

Comment: @BretzL yes and yes.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what exactly you are trying to do, whether data is sensitive, want to remain compliant etc.,

If you not serving sensitive traffic, unencrypted data between ELB and EC2 instances in your VPC is ok. In fact, until 2012 there was no option to encrypt data between ELB and EC2. Now you have `backend cert` to do exactly what you are asking for.

On the other hand, if you feel uncomfortable (you should) with unencrypted data transfer, or want to be compliant (HIPAA, PCI etc.,) you better secure the backend traffic. You should use backend certs. I would.